# How to hide the keyboard if I have a UIView(contains several textview) in Scrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextview

I have several textview in my UIVIew which contained in a scrollview.
First the scollview doesn't not actives when I touched it and want to hide the keyboard after finished the textview editing. So I had build a class name subUIView inherit from scrollview. In that class I overwrite the touch touchbegan events. like the code blow.
   But after that the **textviewbeingediting** function didn't action any more. It's all about **touchbegan** events calling even when I want to edit the textview.
Could you offer me some advise to solve the problem?Thanks

```
//
//  **subUIView.h**
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface subUIView :   UIScrollview
{

 }


@end


//  **subUIView.m**
#import "subUIView.h"

@implementation subUIView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
self.delegate=self;
//return [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

}
return self;}

NSInteger a=0;


- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {   NSLog(@"touch began ");
// If not dragging, send event to next responder
if (!self.dragging)
{
      [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; 
 }}
```

in the code blow  I alloc scrollview from subUIView and code the textviewbeginediting function.

```
//
//  **ReadExperienceInfoViewController.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define ExperienceTableName  @"pockets"
@class subUIView;
@interface ReadExperienceInfoViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate> {
subUIView *scrollView;

UIView *upView;

UITextField *bookNameTextField;
UITextView *bookExprection;
NSString *getFullDateStr;

BOOL dragging;
}

 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *upView;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) subUIView *scrollView;


//
// **ReadExperienceInfoViewController.m**

//- (void)loadView{

scrollView=[[subUIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 960);
scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage :[UIImage imageNamed:@"infomation.png"]];
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
upView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

upView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 960)];
[upView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

UILabel *bookName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 30)];
bookName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
bookName.text = @"Title";
bookName.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
[upView addSubview:bookName];
[bookName release];

bookNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 30)];
bookNameTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bookNameTextField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
bookNameTextField.delegate=self;
[upView addSubview:bookNameTextField];

//lowerView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, 320, 170)];
UILabel  *bookExprectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 200, 30)];
bookExprectionLabel.text = @"Content";
bookExprectionLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
bookExprectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[upView addSubview:bookExprectionLabel];
[bookExprectionLabel release];

bookExprection = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 110, 280, 140)];
bookExprection.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bookExprection.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];    
bookExprection.delegate=self;
[upView addSubview:bookExprection];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" 
                                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                          target:self action:@selector(updateExperience)]
                                          autorelease];

self.title= bookNameStr;       
self.view=scrollView;

}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
upView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 960);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[bookExprection resignFirstResponder];
[bookNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}


-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
NSLog(@"texview dig begin editing");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
if (textView==bookExprection) {
    upView.frame=CGRectMake(0, -80, 320, 0);          
}    
[UIView commitAnimations];  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `subUIView.h` File must implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` Protocol, so your viewcontroller responds to the delegate methods for the text field.

Same for the Scroll view, you have to implement the ScrollView

```
//subUIView.h
@interface subUIView : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>{
//do stuff
}
```

Then of course you must write `scrollView.delegate = self;` so that the viewcontroller responds to the delegatemethods for the scroll view.

Hope this helps

Comment: As I  implement the UITextViewDelegate Protocol and UIScrollViewDelegate in my UIViewcontroller. But you may know that subUIview is a Scrollview class which build for if not dragging or scroll it will call hide keyboard function. After I do that it will catch all the events so the UIViewcontroller's textviewbeginediting and other touch events function will never called. Thanks very much for your advise.